# Area of a quadrilateral proof

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Prove that the area of a quadrilateral is one half the product of the lengths of its diagonals and the sine of the angle between the diagonals.
[image]

Comment: What are your thoughts? (**Hint:** Decompose the quadrilateral into two triangles).

Comment: Nitpicking: if your angle $\theta$ is oriented, it should be $|\sin\theta|$ in the formula.

Comment: As I know it can be proved by drawing parallel to diagonals lines through the points of the quadrilateral.

Answer (score 6):

Hint:

Let $S$ be the area of a triangle, $a,b$ be the length of two edges and $\theta$ be the angle between them, you have the following formula
$$S=\frac{1}{2}ab\sin\theta$$

On more hint: $\sin\theta=\sin(\pi-\theta)$.

Comment: I was also thinking about these formulas but how to use them?

Comment: Try to expand $(a+b)(c+d)$

Comment: I have done that. I have four triangles in the figure above. and the area I get is 1/2(a+b)(c+d) but the problem is where do I get sine from?

Comment: Look at the formula again. $\sin\theta$ is in it.

Comment: I am confused now , I have the proof but still I dont have.

Comment: If I split into two triangles, and apply the above formula, then what is the angle?? It doesnot make sense..

Comment: Split it into FOUR triangles

Comment: I have done that. Then the area of the figure is 1/2(ac+ad+bd+bc) then what?

Comment: The area should be $\frac{1}{2}(ab+ad+bd+bc)\sin\theta$. see if it is equal to $\frac{1}{2}(a+b)(c+d)\sin\theta$

Comment: But this $sin\theta$ is not necessarily same in all four triangles???

Comment: Use the fact that $\sin\theta=\sin(\pi-\theta)$

Answer (score 1):

The area of this quadrilateral can be calculated by summing up the area of its four triangles. For a triangle, its area can be calculated using the formula:
$A=\frac{1}{2}ab\sin\theta$
where $a$ and $b$ are the lengths of two of his sides and $\theta$ is the internal angle between them, so the total area of the quadrilateral is:
$A=\frac{1}{2}ac\sin\theta_1+\frac{1}{2}cb\sin\theta_2+\frac{1}{2}bd\sin\theta_3+\frac{1}{2}da\sin\theta_4$
where the four angles $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$, $\theta_3$ and $\theta_4$ are the internal angles between each couple of edges. By knowing that $\theta_1$ = $\theta_3$ and $\theta_2$ = $\theta_4$, and $\theta_1$ and $\theta_3$ are supplementary angles ($\theta_1 = \pi-\theta_3$), so all the angles have the same $sin$, hence:
$A=\frac{1}{2}ac\sin\theta+\frac{1}{2}cb\sin\theta+\frac{1}{2}bd\sin\theta+\frac{1}{2}da\sin\theta\\=\frac{1}{2}(ac+cb+bd+da)\sin\theta\\=\frac{1}{2}(a+b)(c+d)\sin\theta\\=\frac{1}{2}d1\cdot d2\sin\theta$
where $d1$ and $d2$ are the lengths of the two diagonlas and $\theta$ is any internal angle between them.

Comment: +1. GREAT answer! I noticed you "followed" my Materials Modeling stack exchange site proposal but did not yet click "commit". Would you be able to please commit to it, as we are getting very desperate now to reach 100 committers with 200 rep? We already reached *all*other requirements! https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=N2UwMzc4Zjc2NmNlMzRiMjBjMDA5YjcyNGY0MDhkNDY4ODYyM2FhYTVhZDY5NmQ2NzkwOTZlN2FiMTMxNzE1Y3L1EikMpMALJvCFhfJb8U1nWYJkAqZIwAZWBGAEqsdM0. It would be very much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

!**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwF2m.png)
**
**The proof:

Area of a quadrilateral =
 area of the first triangle + area of the second triangle + area of the third triangle + area of the fourth triangle

= [0.5 .d . b . sin θ ] + [0.5 . b . c . sin (180 - θ) ] + [0.5 . a . c . sin θ ] + [0.5 . d . a . sin (180 - θ) ]

As, sin (180 - θ) = sin θ

Area = [0.5 . d . b . sin θ ] + [0.5 . b . c . sin θ ] + [0.5 . a . c . sin θ ] + [0.5 . d . a . sin θ ]

Area = 0.5 . sin θ . [ (d . b) + (b . c) + (a . c) + (d . a) ]

As, (d . b) + (b . c) = b . (c + d)
and  (a . c) + (d . a) = a . (c + d)

Area = 0.5 . sin θ . [ b . (c + d) + a . ( c + d) ]

Area = 0.5 . sin θ . (c + d) . [b + a]

As, (b + a) = p , (c + d) = q

Area = 0.5 . p . q . sin θ

Comment: Welcome to mathstack exchange. In the future, please use MathJax in order to make your answer more readable

Comment: What are $diag1$ and $diag2$?